# Dask Worker using huge amount of virtual memory (Windows)

Tags: python, memory, dask-distributed

On a remote agent I created 16 workers. The machine (Windows 10)  has 32GB of memory, 6 cores (12 Logical). Looking in Process Explorer we have for each worker: Private Bytes 3,143,692 KB, Working Set: 122,000 KB. From SystemInfo we get 7GB of available virtual memory for a total virtual memory of 66 GB. If we stop the workers we get 54.6 GB of available virtual memory. Why is a worker using so much virtual memory. Is this something we can control? Our distributed python task are very simple, each one just runs an application executable in a subprocess. We are actually using Dask to replace our Celery framework, a Celery worker uses about 40MB of virtual memory

Comment: Dask workers don't generally take a huge amount of memory, so this must be something specific to your workflow. So in order to help we'll need more details on the job specification. Can you try to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Here I am talking  about virtual memory. Anyway it is easy to reproduce. Run dask-scheduler.exe in a console and dask-worker.exe {scheduler} --nthreads 1 --nprocs 4 in an other console. On my laptop each worker is using abaout 1GB of virtual memory. On my remote mahchine each worker is using almost 4GB of virtual memory. Both machines are running Windows 10